# How to read value form Blazor after update it with JavaScript?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, blazor

I'm trying to read value from Blazor after update it with JavaScript, although the value is changed,  Blazor still read it as null ?

Any hints ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the value directly from JavaScript, you have to invoke a method in your C# component or page code.

**Razor:**

```
@code {
    public string MyValue { get; set; }
    
    [JsInvokable]
    public static void UpdateMyValue(string newValue)
    {
        this.MyValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
function UpdateValue() {
    DotNet.invokeMethod('SampleApp', 'UpdateMyValue', 'Here is a new value');
}
```

More details [in the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-3.1), including how to call an instance method instead of a static, to call asynchronous methods and handle the result, and how to avoid memory leaks on the DotNetObjectReference.

Comment: Thanks very much.

The first solution works but I have a question, Since the I make the property static will it be shared across all the sessions ?

Regards

Comment: Keyword 'this' is not valid in a static property, static method, or static field initializer .. how it works for you.. i have no idea ..